# The data isn't storing in the array

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to store some data in the array call `holder` and the problem is that when I display that array nothing being store in it and I don't know what is wrong even though the logic seem to be right for me. The data is coming from an array call `sender` I'm using two dimension array to store it up to 5 at MAX.

```
        for (int t = 0; t < strlen(sender) && stop == false; t++){ // stop is the bool that created to break the loop
            if (sender[t] != ';'){ // all the data being store in the holder will be separated by ';'
                holder[d][t] = sender[t];
            }
            if (sender[t] == ';') // if the sender at position of 't' number meet ';' then plus one to start store the next data
                d++;
            if (holder[d][t] == '\0'){ // if it meet the '\0' then exit from the for loop
                holder[d][t] = '\0';   // If `;` found, null terminate the copied destination.
                stop = true;

            }
        }
```

This is the sender array `"Hello;How;Is;Good Bye"`

The output is

`Your holder-----> '`

`Actual holder---> 'Hello'`

Comment: Is there a starting value for d? (before the loop?)
`holder[d][t] = sender[t];`

Comment: Please could you indent your code snippet properly?

Comment: @OfirBaruch yes, it's initialize to `0`

Comment: @OliCharlesworth So sorry I'm trying my best to do it the way you guys want

Comment: What's the purpose of this code?

Comment: @OfirBaruch the purpose is to store the data that send from the array `sender` which come all in one phrase and to separate them in 5 pieces or more depend on the data send and separated by `';'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't understand why you're not allowed to use `break`. Maybe you could clarify the objective of the exercise? Otherwise, maybe this code solves your problem? I would normally have used another technique, but since you said that you're not allowed to use `break`...

```
int pos = 0, col = 0, row = 0;
do {
  if(';' == sender[pos] || 0 == sender[pos]) {
    holder[row++][col] = 0;
    col = 0;
  } else {
    holder[row][col++] = sender[pos];
  }
} while(0 != sender[pos++]);
```

Comment: +1, I was in the process of posting almost identical code with a `for` loop.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yep, I would've used a `for` loop too, with a check for 0 inside and a `break` to get out, but without the possibility to use `break` I figured this was better since you need to terminate the last substring somehow. (Doing it outside of the loop seems ugly to me.)

Comment: Thanks this code worked for me I will just probably going to figure out the way to write it in my own way :/

Comment: You can just run the `for` loop index from 0 to `strlen(sender)` inclusive, no `break` needed and it correctly terminates the last string.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Yes, but it still requires an additional variable. Plus, the `strlen` function still runs through the string so there's not much of an efficiency gain from doing it. Furthermore, you need to `#include <cstring>`, which I rarely use. Don't know if a `for` loop would really make more sense in this case.

Answer (score 2):

One issue is that you are using t for both the index for holder and the index for your input string.  This may work for the first section, but not for the ones afterwards.

You also want to store a null terminator when you hit a semicolon.

Comment: Well, I didn't though of that one, but even the first one didn't seem to work? :(

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem with the last condition `if (holder[d][t] == '\0')`.
There are 2 chars in this condition (`\0`) but the `holder[d][t]` is only one char,
therefore this condition will never be `true`.
What's about the next code?

```
int aStringLength = strlen(sender);
int t = 0;
while( stop == false )
{
 if(t == aStringLength)
   stop = true;

 if(sender[t] != ';')
 {
   holder[d][i] = sender[t];
   i++;
 }
 else
 {
   d++;
   i = 0;
 }

 t++;
}
```

Comment: You could write `for(int t=0; ; ++t)` instead of using a `while` loop and two additional statements. There's no null termination after the substrings at the moment. Also, why not `break` out of the loop instead of assigning a boolean flag?

Comment: Hi, Thanks and I'm still getting empty result :(

Comment: @aliquis , you're right. Ali , let's break this code up - add a printing command to all the variables in each and every step.
We are missing here somehthing.

Comment: @aliquis `break` was not permit in the assignment so we have to use other option.

Comment: @OfirBaruch I'm trying to see what is missing because even I tried the code you gave me then after all I the result it saying `' '` which is weird

Comment: Simply add `printf ("Characters: %c %d %d \n", sender[t], t , d);` before the end of the loop and write the output of it.

Comment: All the value looks correct there I can see all the value, but once I use `printf("%s", holder);` then I just see an empty string =.="